# Is there a way to view the current input source in vim?

Tags: vim

When using vim in a non-English language environment, mistakes in mis-entering command often occur.

To prevent this, is there a way to view the current input source on the statusline?
For example, EN or JP.

like MS word bottom bar
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim doesn't have that information so it can't expose it, which is not exactly a problem since your desktop environment already does.

If you *really* want to duplicate that information in your Vim status line, then you will have to find what external command to call, and then find a way to consume the information that doesn't slow Vim to a crawl because the status line is refreshed several times per second.

Now, your question is really two questions:

- How to get the information?
- How to show it in the statusline?

The answer to the first question depends on your desktop environment, which you didn't disclose. You will have to look around on your own, on more specialised forums.

The answer to the second question is irrelevant without an answer to the first one but you can look up `:help 'statusline'` and `:help system()` if you are curious.

Anyway, you already have the information in your desktop environment's menu bar/task bar/whatever, so why bother?

Answer (score 1):

Vim has modes. In Normal mode where it is supposed to stay most of the time all commands consist of latin letters by default. Therefore, using OS level keyboard layout switch cannot be recommended. Instead, Vim has a feature called "keymap". Vim keymap is only active in Insert or Command-line mode never affecting the Normal mode.

So, Vim never cares what is your active keyboard layout on OS level and you won't expect an easy way showing it. On the other side, Vim keymap name is accessible either as `b:keymap_name` variable or `%k` format specifier for the statusline option. So it is pretty easy to add it.